# Получение значения из БД

Tags: java, android, firebase

Хочу встаить значения в Map до этоого вывел лог все ок но добаил их в Map  начал ругаться

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Shot" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
    Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
    String name = map.get("Name");
    String age = map.get("Age");
    Log.v("E_VALUE", "Name: " + name );
    Log.v("E_VALUE", "Age: " + age );
```

Ошибка

> 10-17 11:31:57.208 18095-18095/com.example.elvir.firedb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.elvir.firedb, PID: 18095
>                                                                             com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at com.example.elvir.firedb.MainActivity$1$override.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:35)
>                                                                                 at com.example.elvir.firedb.MainActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
>                                                                                 at com.example.elvir.firedb.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:0)
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что класс `Map` имеет параметры, которые не указаны в обращении к getValue.

Попробуйте получить значение и привести его к нужному типу:

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
...
```

P.S. если ввести сообщение об ошибке в Google, то первый результат — [вопрос на Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688031/class-java-util-map-has-generic-type-parameters-please-use-generictypeindicator). Там в ответах есть также решение с помощью `GenericTypeIndicator`

Comment: Спасибо сработало но яже все прально сделал непойму в чем ошибка)

Comment: @elik вы пытались получить `Map.class`, в то время как реальный объект имеет тип `Map<String, String>`

Comment: аа теперь яснее